# kill process and get the output c#

Tags: c#, outputstream, kill-process

Hi am creating a console application that executes another windows console application.

Sometimes the application never end its execution, an I need to force kill it, if exceeded a time. When the application is force killed I am unable to get the output of the application.

There is a way to get the output before killing the running process in order to write to a file or get it after killing it?

```
     Process process = new Process();
     process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
     process.StartInfo.FileName = "robocopy.exe";
     process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
     process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     process.StartInfo.Arguments = parameters;

     process.Start();

 //set the maximum allowed time in which the robocopy lives 
                if (process.WaitForExit(15000))
                {
                   logInfo = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();                     
                   //do something else
                }
                else
                {
                   process.Kill();
                   logInfo = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();                       
                   //write the output to a file

                 }
```

Comment: It depends, if the output is sitting in a buffer, it goes away when the process terminates.  If you can convince the child process to flush its output buffers, then you can read it through the pipe.

Comment: Use logInfo = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); before process.Kill();

Comment: This is relevant https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2007/09/26/the-standard-output-buffer-stuffer/

Comment: @viveknuna i have already tried to set the process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); before process.Kill(); but the problem is that it doesnot read to the end until the process have ended. because the aplication never ends, causes my application to get stuck in these step.